# How to check for occurrence of single quote using getchar() in C?

Tags: c

`getchar()` can be used to find a particular character from input file by comparing the desired letter with every input character read by `getchar()` in C as in following code.

How can we find occurrence of single quote itself?

We cannot compare quote by writing it within pair of quotes as we do for characters

```
int c;
while((c=getchar)!=EOF)
{
  if(c=='A')
    printf("CHARACTER FOUND");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Escape](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) the quote: `if (c == '\'')`.

Comment: This could have been a comment. Please explain him about escaping characters and special characters such as `'\n'`.